# Display SearchView in ActionBar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am trying to display a `SearchView` inside the `ActionBar` of my activity. I followed android developer guide here [here](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html)
But no `SearchView` is displayed and I cannot figure out why. 
Here there is the code of my activity

```
    public class SearchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private String query;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity_layout);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            this.query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Toast.makeText(this,query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

here the is the `serachable.xml` file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

here there is the `options_menu.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

and this is the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
              android:label="SearchActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>


    </activity>
```

the only strange thing is that this line (`android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"`) in the `options_menu.xml` file is highlighted in red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in your options_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

And this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
    android:label="SearchActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchActivity" />
</activity>
```

And this in your SearchActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.e("query", intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I can see the icon but when I click on it nothing happens, no input text is showed up(in order to make the query) and keyboard is not opened

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that but if I add the four lines that you added in the onCreateOptionsMenu method applications crashes with nullpointerexception at the third line that you added. (I also added the meta data in the manifest)

Comment: it crashes here SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

Comment: @FF91, I edited the line above that one, try it again

Comment: it crashes before: here SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE); always with null pointer exception

Comment: no, it still crashes here searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

Comment: @FF91 Can you edit the post with your actual code and put the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, hope this helps!

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

\res\xml\searchable.xml:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.searchview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    return true;
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following code

menu_search.xml

```
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".SearchActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

I think you are making a mistake in the above code.
Are you using appcompat library?
if no, the above code should work.
if yes, try using `app:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction` and 
`app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` instead of `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`

manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="SearchActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".SearchActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>
```

SearchActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}

    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    System.out.println("onNewIntent SearchResults");
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        System.out.println("Received query: " + query);
    }
}
```